# Update Record and Insert Data from One Table Via Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (Table 1) which is a list of employees and data points about them. The data that populated Table 1 is regularly changed and added to in its source system and then is loaded into another table (Table 2) via a CSV.

If data changes for a certain employee, I want to update that employees record in Table 1 and then append that changed employee to Table 1 along with any new employees from Table 2 that didn't already exist in Table 1.

Example:

Table1:

```
Status |  ID  |  Name  |  Department  | Title 
    
Active   767    John       Tech         Analyst
Active   789    Alex       Tech         Courier
```

Table2:

```
Status |  ID  |  Name  |  Department  | Title 
    
Active   767    John       Tech         Director -- the title changed for this employee
Active   789    Alex       Tech         Courier
```

Desired Output of Table1:

```
Status |  ID  |  Name  |  Department  | Title 
        
Active   767    John       Tech         Director
Changed  767    John       Tech         Analyst
Active   789    Alex       Tech         Courier
```

With the query below, I am attempting to insert this data via an outer join however I am producing duplicates of each row, when I only want to add employees who have changed their department, title, etc. and any new employees that don't already exist in Table1

How can I insert this data without duplicating all the roles.

Query:

```
UPDATE [DATABASE].[dbo].[CBC_legacy]
SET [Position Status] = 'Changed'
FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[CBC_data] CBC
WHERE (CBC.[Employee ID] = [CBC_legacy].[employee ID] AND (CBC.[Job Title] <> [CBC_legacy].[Job Title] OR CBC.[Home Department] <> [CBC_legacy].[Home Department] OR CBC.[Annual Salary] <> [CBC_legacy].[Annual Salary]))


INSERT INTO [DATABASE].[dbo].[CBC_legacy] (
       [Position Status]
      ,[Employee ID]
      ,[Full Legal Name]
      ,[Annual Salary]
      ,[Job Title]
      ,[Home Department]
SELECT
       [CBC].[Position Status]
      ,[CBC].[Employee ID]
      ,[CBC].[Full Legal Name]
      ,[CBC].[Annual Salary]
      ,[CBC].[Job Title]
      ,[CBC].[Home Department]

FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[CBC_data] AS CBC

FULL JOIN [DATABASE].[dbo].[CBC_legacy] AS CBCL 
                ON [CBC].[Employee ID] = [CBCL].[Employee ID] 
                AND [CBC].[Job Title] = [CBCL].[Job Title] 
                AND [CBC].[Home Department] = [CBCL].[Home Department] 
                AND [CBC].[Annual Salary] = [CBCL].[Annual Salary]

ORDER BY [Full Legal Name]

SELECT * FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[CBC_legacy] ORDER BY [Full Legal Name]
```

Comment: It looks like you are either the same person who asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72037665/sql-insert-data-into-table-with-full-outer-join) or you are maybe in the same class and should get together and have a chat?

Comment: @DaleK But I do want to insert someone with the same ID if any of the other columns about them changed, the checking not exists would exclude those, no?

Comment: Yes, just re-read your question. Seems you never want an update, your sample data shows you inserting a new row when a value changes. So a left join will give you a match if the records already exist and you can use `case` to determine the inserted values.

Comment: I do want an udpate, if an employee has had changed info, I want to change their status to "Changed" and then insert that employee and their new info into the table while persevering what info they had before. I need to see what they were before and what they are now.

Comment: OK, then you need a joined update, see the docs for how to do that.

Comment: Ok Ill try that and post a new question if it doesnt work

Comment: So for changed rows you want to update *and* insert?